# cannot install cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Tags: cordova, wkwebview

Long story short. Executing cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
and getting Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try the long story, it would be easier to help you

Comment: Thank you :) I am still trying to solve it - but if I cannot I would search help

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following workaround:

1. Execute this command: `sudo npm install git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git#master --production --save`, enter your password if required.
2. Then try the plugin add command: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`.